# linux weblogic stop script pid

Tags: linux, shell, weblogic

I am writing a stop script and using the code below but this is not working.

```
PID=`ps -ef | grep java | grep "nodemanager" | awk '{print $2}'`

if [ ${PID} ]
then
   kill ${PID}
fi
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: What isn't working? If you have more than one process running this will return multiple PIDs... but if it's literally a single process this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Does the command match multiple lines, for example because of parameters to the managed servers like `-Dweblogic.nodemanager.ServiceEnabled`?

Is the command line too long for `ps -ef` to display fully (Solaris, for example, truncates the parameters; use `/usr/ucb/ps -auxww` to get the full command line)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of killing the process you could use Weblogic's own functionality to shut down the server by giving for example the following command:

```
java -cp /opt/bea10/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.jar weblogic.Admin -url t3://localhost:7701/ -username admin_username -password admin_password FORCESHUTDOWN -ignoreExistingSessions server_name
```

You may need to modify the path to weblogic.jar and/or url to your actual admin url (if these differ from the default). Also replace `admin_username`, `admin_password` and `server_name` with actual values.